# HttpPost Java(Android) to ObjC(iOS)

Tags: android, ios, http, post

`

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
    JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
    String response = null;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        try {
            // setup the returned values in case
            // something goes wrong
            json.put("success", false);
            json.put("info", "something wrong.");
            // add the users's info to the post params
            userObj.put("email", mEmail);
            userObj.put("password", mPassword);
            holder.put("user", userObj);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString(), "utf-8");
            post.setEntity(se);

            // setup the request headers
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
            json = new JSONObject(response);`
.......
```

==========

Up, Java code source. written by someone.
Down, Objective-C code source.(request is a pointer of NSMutableURLRequest), I type this code.

===========

```
    NSMutableDictionary *datas = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [datas setValue:@"doremi@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
    [datas setValue:@"zxcvbnmm" forKey:@"password"];

    NSString *httpbody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@",datas];
    NSData *httpbodydata = [httpbody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:httpbodydata];
    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[httpbodydata length]];
    [request addValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

===========

whats different between that two codes?

in result, Java works fine but Objc cant send json object!

I just want send like Java code.

and, please tell me what StringEntity do in that java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can help you with the **iOS POST method**, if i were you i will try with the **AFNetworking**, it will be much more easier to implement the request and also will be similar to the java solution managing JSON messages. I let you some code that could help:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```